# I tried to download PyCrypto for Python 3.7 but failed

Tags: python, pycrypto

I ran command prompt as administrator then typed pip install pycrypto
and got this error message:

> Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Berkay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yikt7auh\pycrypto\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\Berkay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rjhqqr19\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Berkay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yikt7auh\pycrypto\

Comment: Hi there, please look at this [guide how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easily installing python packages on windows install [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html).

1.Open search and search for anaconda as follows:

[image: Image1]

2.Click on Anaconda Prompt, this will open a Anaconda command line for windows 
 as given below:

[image: Image2]

3. For installing pycrypto write the command

   ```
   conda install -c anaconda pycrypto
   ```

   as given [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pycrypto). In this way pycrypto is installed using conda in windows environment:

   [image: Image3]
4. To execute a script using anaconda in windows, first get the current working 
   directory used by conda on your system using:

   ```
    import os
    os.getcwd()
   ```

   This will give the current working directory.

   [image: Image4]
5. Then come out of python compiler into anaconda command line using:

   ```
    import sys
    sys.exit()
   ```

   [image: Image5]
6. Put your code in current working directory as shown below:

   [image: Image6]
7. Now execute this code using anaconda command line as shown below:

   [image: Image7]

This concludes the tutorial for installing packages and compiling python code using conda on windows.

Comment: Doesn't recognize conda as a command maybe I should add to enviromental variables

Comment: I ran anaconda prompt and installed it somehow but when i did before the final code it wrote pylint 2.1.1 requires colorama; sys_platform == "win32", which is not installed. But still installed it but when I my engine in pycharms it didnt recognize my crpyto modules

Comment: @Strinix I hope edition to the original answer will solve your problem.